# Which spark memory setting is for pandas_udf execution

Tags: pandas, pyspark, user-defined-functions

Executor's memory is a sum of the following ([source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/Client.scala#L344))

```
spark.executor.memory
spark.executor.memoryOverhead
spark.executor.pyspark.memory
```

Which one is used by the execution of the `pandas_udf` function?

In case of a moderate data size (3000 partitions each ~50MB) and advanced pandas_udf function which memory should be considered first in case of OOM errors?